# How to add a string to field input without showing it?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm building an app in Rails and I have a form where users can input their age. When they submit `20` I want to pass it to the next page as `20 years old`.

```
<%= form_tag age_path, method: "POST", id: 'age', remote: true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'age-question', nil %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit", id:"submit-age" %>
<% end %>
```

I added this bit and it works, however before it submits it adds to the input field `years old`, and I wouldn't like to show that to the user.

```
$('#age').submit(function() {
  var txt = $('#age-question');
  txt.val(txt.val() + " years old");
```

});

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: you can always add that in the backend and avoid all the things that you are currently doing in jquery, you can do it either in your controller or model

Comment: This just seems like a bad idea since you should be storing the age as a numerical format and then presenting it in a localized format. If you have a column named age and its a string that’s a major WTF moment for other developers that might have to work in the project.

Answer (score 0):

The form sends data to the Rails using `params`. So, you can achieve what you are trying to do in the controller.

For example, if your form is submitting to the `ages_controller.rb` and assuming that `create` method is handling the input then you can do the following inside the `create` method.

```
def create    
  params[:age][:age_question] = (params[:age][:age_question] + " years old") if params[:age][:age-question]
  # some other code
end
```

Another alternative is to use the [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) in your Model. You can perform certain actions at the certain point of object lifecycle.